# О междометии в конце фразы: «Какие точки тут могут быть, о.»

Tags: междометие

> И смотри: первые три позиции нависают над телом основного текста, так?
>   (…) Какие точки тут могут быть, о.

Может быть такое, что авторская «о» подразумевала другое междометие (или частицу), типа *моё почтение*, *увы*, *вот так*, *вот*, *вот именно*, и тогда пунктуационное решение должно было быть иным? Речь не могла же идти о междометии с самостоятельной интонацией (*От удивления мог произнести только один звук: «О!»*)?

Comment: На опечатку больше всего похоже. После этого "о." ещё что-то есть? Контекст-то каков?  Напомнило: "Такие-то пилоты, как Вы, на улице не валяются-о!"(с)Мимино :) Но вот этому "-о!" лингвистическое объяснение есть.

Comment: tum Автор объяснил: не опечатка. Их полно у Петрушевской, о.

Answer (score 1):

Не находя примеров в русском, обратимся к соседним языкам. В них бытуют тождественные нашим ***вот*** и ***вот так*** указательные частицы с функцией подтверждения истинности высказывания: ***вот*** = ось, оце, ото (укр.), вось (бел.); ***так*** = отак, так-то (укр.).

Что же это? Это украинизм и пока не освоенное русским литературным подражание, а в части пунктуации — при правильном обособлении частицы — спорное (на письме) завершение фразы.

Answer (score 1):

Контрпример:

*Какая точка может быть внутри кавычек (если она не сигнализирует о сокращении), у.*

Это укор я так обозначила, у'ом: русский такой, сокрушённый такой укор, а не украинизм или недоосвоенное подражание, о.

Таких конструкций полно у Петрушевской.